# Any way to download stored text in session storage as file attachment to browser?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I store some data in `sessionStorage`/`localStorage`. Is there any way to download that data as file attachment directly to the browser?

Comment: Depending on the kind of data you want to save, you could try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4551467/472974

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: @janaravi I have a very large string stored in `localstorage`/`sessionstorage`. I need to download that string as attachment in a form of a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get that data from the storage and use [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) api to create new file in the memory

```
let myFile = new File(data, "Filename.txt[anything]",{type:"plain/text"}]);
let url = URL.createObjectURL(myFile);
let a = document.createElement("a");
a.href(url);
a.setAttribute("download","data.txt");
a.click();
```